# Wrong connected user in Salesforce for DocuSign

Tags: user, docusign

Here is the situation and my problem :

I need to configure a In-Person Signing for multiple users.

Here is my problem : When User1 go to the "Salesforce for DocuSign" app or wants to use DocuSign, Salesforce automatically connect to DocuSign. Later, on the same computer, if a second user uses DocuSign, Salesforce switches the "connected" user to User1 (and switch back to the real connected user when he changes of app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !
The 2 users were sharing the same email adress.
In this case, Salesforce is sending all the documents to the same account (in this case, User1). DocuSign doesn't support very well two accounts with the same email adress.